# Azure Cli PowerShell - how to pass list query results (array) as inline Parameters?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-rm-template

In Azure Cli with Powershell. What I'm trying to do is list out all the existing KV secret names and then pass the array in as an inline parameter for '**az deployment group create**' command.
[image]

However, seems like the command doesn't like the format of JSON array so I got this error: **ERROR: Failed to parse string as JSON**

Upon checking docus, seems like it want something like **"['value1','value2']"** but my query result is **["t1","t2"]**, so it will throw the error out.
[image]

This surprised me as the query result are not supported natively by Azure CLI, wondering how can I convert my query results to the right format?

Answer (score 0):

```html
$formattedOutput = @()
foreach($line in $secretNamesArray) {
    $formattedOutput += "'"+$line+"'"
}

$existingSecretNames = "[" + ($formattedOutput -join ",") + "]"
```

Figured out, have to transform it.... what a wonderful job MS...

also remember to wrap the results with double quote as well like:

```
--parameters existingSecretNames="$existingSecretNames"
```

So it will pass something in like "['t1', 't2', 't3']"

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `$existingSecretNames = ConvertTo-Json @($secretNamesArray) -Compress` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no it won't work, as MS wants single quote but your command will return things with double quote  ["[","  \"AuthClientId\",","  \"AuthClientSecret\",","  \"AuthGrantType\",","  \"AuthPassword\",","  \"AuthScope\",","  \"AuthUrl\",","  \"AuthUsername\",","  \"HubspotApiKey\"","]"]

Comment: So you're saying a string looking like the result of that: ``"`"$(ConvertTo-Json @('abc', 'def') -Compress)`""`` is not what MS wants?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon  No, my query result is some JSON array like ["t1", "t2"], what MS want is "['t1', 't2']".  Please note the single/double quote difference. Your second command will give result like ["abc","def"], but MS want single quote. Something like "['abc','def']".  It has to be like this per my last picture of their docu

Comment: So this `$secretNamesArray = "['{0}']" -f ($secretNamesArray -join "','")` would work?

Comment: @Theo, Ah, Thanks for the one-line sulotion. I'm not good at PowerShell. I think yours will work .

Comment: Only one way to find out ;) Can you let us know if that works for you?

Comment: Since PowerShell 6.2, you can use the [Join-String cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string), too. `$secretNamesArray | ConvertFrom-Json | Join-String -SingleQuote -Separator "," -OutputPrefix "[" -OutputSuffix "]"`